# Why does my navigation bar disappear from my split view when I rotate on iPhone 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**The Problem**

I have a problem with my split view.  It works fine on iPhone and iPad simulators, but on the iPhone 6+ I lose the navigation bar after rotating the device.  Here's what happens on the 6+ simulator:

- I start the app and it presents a + button in the navigation bar.  I tap this button.
- It loads a view controller over the existing view.  A navigation bar, as expected, is visible with a working back button.
- I turn the device horizontally.  As intended the new controller appears in the Master section, with an empty detail section on the right. Unfortunately the navigation bar dissapears.
- When I turn the device vertically the navigation bar does not reappear.

In fact when I turn the device horizontally it seems the navigation controller is removed from the stack (I've observed this from outputting the contents of splitViewContoller.viewControllers).

**My Code**

The test application is simply the Master Detail template with a few modifications.

I've added a new "Add Item" controller and then created a show segue from the Master view's "+" button.  The "Add Item" controller is blank, just a blue background.

The DetailViewController has a timerStarted boolean value that is true when the detail view is being used and false when it isn't.  The master view is hidden when the detail is in use and displayed when it isn't.

Here's the relevant code (there's nothing interesting in AppDelegate as it's no longer a split view delegate, and MasterViewController has no interaction as the button works via the storyboard)

DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    var collapseDetailViewController = true


    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    var timerStarted: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.changeTimerStatus()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.description
                self.timerStarted = true
            }
        }
    }

    func changeTimerStatus() {
        if self.timerStarted {
            if splitViewController!.collapsed == false {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryHidden
                })
            }
            collapseDetailViewController = false
        } else {
            if splitViewController!.collapsed {
                self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0].popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } else {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                    self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
                })
            }
            collapseDetailViewController = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        splitViewController?.delegate = self
        self.disabledScreen.hidden = false
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(disabledScreen)
        self.configureView()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if splitViewController!.collapsed == false && self.timerStarted == false {
            splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
        }
    }

    @IBAction func closeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.timerStarted = false
    }

    func primaryViewControllerForExpandingSplitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if timerStarted == true {
            splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryHidden
        } else {
            splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
        }
        return nil
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController!) -> Bool {
        return collapseDetailViewController
    }
}
```

AddItemViewController

```
import UIKit

class AddItemViewController: UIViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    var collapseDetailViewController = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.splitViewController?.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.splitViewController?.delegate = self
        self.collapseDetailViewController = false
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.splitViewController?.delegate = nil
        self.collapseDetailViewController = true
    }

    func primaryViewControllerForExpandingSplitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return self
    }

    func primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController!) -> Bool {
        return collapseDetailViewController
    }
}
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.  I read a article which I had originally missed because it focuses on changing the detail view rather than the master.  As it turns out, the split view works better if I just manage the detail and then the master will take care of itself.  Since I never want to change the detail I can simply add the following to my split view delegate:

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    return (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailView") as! UIViewController)
}
```

Once this is done, I no longer lose the navigation bar.